# SSL not working Apache2

Tags: magento2, ssl

I'm trying to set up my SSL certificate but the site still says that https is unsecure.

I've edited the 000-default.conf as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName millingtonmayers.co.uk
    Redirect permanent / https://millingtonmayers.co.uk/
 </VirtualHost>

 <VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName millingtonmayers.co.uk
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /home/bensleym/millingtonmayers.co.uk.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/bensleym/millingtonmayers.co.uk.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /home/bensleym/intermediate.crt
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless

    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
 </VirtualHost>
```

The redirect doesn't seem to be working either any ideas?

Comment: sudo a2enmod ssl
sudo service apache2 restart

Have you done also this 2 command.

Comment: Yes i Have also run those two commands

Comment: This is self-signed certificate?

Comment: check here https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=https://millingtonmayers.co.uk/